# Qual a necessidade de se declarar o construtor/super de uma classe extendida?

Tags: javascript, herança, construtor

Tenho uma classe, exemplo:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(raca) {
    this._raca = raca;
  }

  get raca() {
    return this._raca;
  }

  printRaca = function() {
    console.log(this._raca);
  }
}
```

E aí eu estendo ela desta forma:

```js
class Cachorro extends Animal {
 
}
```

Reparem que eu não chamei o construtor, nem o `super()`. Entretanto, se eu instanciar a classe `Cachorro` ela funciona da mesma forma que a classe `Animal`, e eu posso pegar o `this._raca` mesmo sem ter chamado o `constructor(raca) { super(raca) }` e utilizá-lo normalmente, vejam:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(raca) {
    this._raca = raca;
  }

  get raca() {
    return this._raca;
  }

  printRaca = function() {
    console.log(this._raca);
  }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal {
 
}

var dog = new Cachorro('poodle');
console.log(dog.raca); //'poodle'
dog.printRaca(); // 'poodle'
```

Qual a necessidade então de chamar o construtor e o `super()`? Existe alguma consequência em não chamá-los?

Comment: Eu reparei que dá erro.

Comment: Onde? Eu fiz aqui várias vezes e não tive nenhum erro, inclusive rodando o snippet aqui mesmo no site funciona.

Comment: `SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported`

Comment: Consegue me dizer ao menos por que funciona para mim e não para você? Não tenho nada de especial em meu navegador, estou usando o chrome normal num ubuntu 18.0

Comment: No Google Chrome funciona, no Firefox não, dando o erro "*SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported*"

Comment: O problema de incompatibilidade está em fazer `printRaca = function...` ao invés de declará-lo como um método normal da classe, `printRaca() {...}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083707/how-to-fix-syntaxerror-fields-are-not-currently-supported-error-in-javascript https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Toda classe tem um construtor padrão criado que você nem vê, se não tivesse não poderia instanciar a classe. Em classes que são derivadas de outras esse construtor faz a chamada para o construtor da classe base mesmo sem você ver que tem lá. Só é necessário fazer isto se você precisa de um construtor que faça algo mais específico. Neste caso é necessário porque precisa inicializar o construtor da base com um argumento, a classe derivada não tem como adivinhar isso. Porém o JS tenta adivinhar e ele pode acertar. Neste caso a linguagem tanta facilitar sua vida, correndo o risco de fazer algo errado, e cria um construtor para você que recebe os mesmos argumentos que tem que passar para o construtor base.

A maioria dos códigos fazem muito mais do que é visível. Por alguma razão, especialmente programadores JavaScript acreditam que quanto menos código se vê menos está fazendo e mais rápido é, quando é o oposto, "sempre" tem algo escondido sendo executado.

Se você criar um construtor seu e não chamar o `super()` de forma adequada não vai construir o objeto de um jeito que possa ser usado adequadamente ou vai até gerar um erro. Por isso precisa entender [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Veja que, ao contrário da premissa da pergunta, assim não funciona:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(raca) {
        this._raca = raca;
    }
    get raca() {
        return this._raca;
    }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal {}

var x = new Cachorro();
console.log(x.raca);
```

E assim funciona:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(raca) {
        this._raca = raca;
    }
    get raca() {
        return this._raca;
    }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal {
    constructor(raca) { super(raca) }
}

var x = new Cachorro("raça");
console.log(x.raca);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Inheritance.js).

Note que tem erro no código da pergunta e não funciona em todo navegador, então para todos efeitos para web ele é um código inválido e não deve ser usado.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonada andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @Maniero, vou te incomodar um pouco... Não entendi porque tu diz que teus dois exemplos funcionam diferente, mas eles se comportam de maneira parecida quando a instanciação recebe os mesmos parâmetros. [Exemplo](https://codepen.io/fernandosavio/pen/aeWOag?editors=0012). O primeiro retorna `undefined` porque `raca` é `undefined` no teu primeiro exemplo. Se você passar uma string no construtor do primeiro exemplo, funcionará como o segundo.

Comment: @fernandosavio de fato faltou escrever sobre isso, o fato da pergunta dele ter um erro e não dar pra testar em qq situação acabou confundindo as coisas, complementei sobre isso.