# Qual o motivo de se usar "super()" antes de se criar as variáveis da classe filha?

Tags: javascript, classes, herança, ecmascript-6

Encontrei esta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400295/qual-a-necessidade-de-se-declarar-o-construtor-super-de-uma-classe-extendida) que fala quase do mesmo assunto porém o foco dela é sobre acesso a métodos da classe pai. E minha dúvida é saber qual o motivo do uso de `super()` antes da declaração de variáveis na classe filha, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class List{

 constructor(){
   this.data = [];
 }

 add(data){
  this.data.push(data);
 }
 showdata(){
   console.log(this.data);
 }
}
```

```
class TodoList extends List{

   constructor(){

      //qual a finalidade deste super para a criação de variáveis na classe filha ?
      super(); 
      this.owner = "John";
   }

  showmeowner(){

    console.log(this.owner);

  }

}

const MyList = new TodoList();
```

Se eu retiro o `super()` do construtor da classe `TodoList` o navegador me retorna o seguinte erro:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'owner' of undefined
    at new TodoList (bundle.js:54)
    at bundle.js:68**

Como a propriedade `owner` pode estar como `undefined`se ela está no construtor da classe `TodoList`? Porque o `super()`é necessário nesta situação ?

Answer (score 0):

Em resumo tecnicamente:

1. Quando uma função regular é executada com **new**, ela cria um **objeto
   vazio e o atribui a this**.
2. Mas quando um construtor derivado (Herdado) é executado, ele não
       faz isso. Ele espera que o construtor pai faça esse trabalho.

Em outras palavras é uma especificação da linguagem.

Entre neste site: https://javascript.info/class-inheritance e procure por este título: 'Overriding constructor'. É mais detalhado e técnico. Se você quiser é um ótimo site para aprender javascript moderno.